# Does Git do versioning per package or per whole project in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, git, ssis, versioning, business-intelligence

I have a SSIS project containing around 50 packages. I want to do versioning with Git. I'm wondering if Git will do the job per package or per project? Thanks

Comment: Neither, Source Control software keeps a history of the files.

Comment: Git does versioning per all files in the repository. Git does not know about packages or projects.